# REGEX for MySQL Query alpha-numeric values with special characters

Tags: mysql, regex

What is the best way for me to search this type of value via regular expression in MySQL?

"ABCDE/+19876543210@abc-def"

`ABCDE/` represents a specific value that does not change

`@abc-def` also represents specific value that does not change

My unsuccessful attempt below:

```
SELECT BLAH
FROM BLOOP
WHERE (bloop.field REGEXP'^\\ABCDE/+1(123|234|345|456)[1-9]{7}@abc-def$')
```

Comment: you really want the 3 digit followed by digit `1` to be either of these  `(123|234|345|456)` ?

Comment: yes. I am looking for phone numbers within specific area codes

Comment: Bug: `[1-9]` --> `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` is a regexp metacharacter, so you have to escape it if you want to match a literal `+`. And because `\` is a string metacharacter, you have to escape it too.

```
mysql> select 'ABCDE/+19876543210@abc-def' regexp 
  '^ABCDE/\\+1(123|234|345|456)[0-9]{7}@abc-def$' as is_match;
+----------+
| is_match |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'ABCDE/+12346543210@abc-def' regexp 
  '^ABCDE/\\+1(123|234|345|456)[0-9]{7}@abc-def$' as is_match;
+----------+
| is_match |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
```

I don't know why you had `\\` in your regexp pattern, because that doesn't match the sample string.

I'm not sure what your digit triples are about. Are they phone area codes? Are you planning to list every area code?

Comment: I am looking to match specific area codes and then the remaining 7 digits can vary.

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer showing a non-match and a match, based on the selected area codes. That's copy & pasted from a test I ran in MySQL 5.6.37, to prove it works.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't escaped `+`. it has a special meaning in regex which means one or more time.

You can use this one

```
^ABCDE\/\\+1(123|234|345|456)[1-9]{7}@abc-def$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IYZGXW/1/)